# How to restrict the size of xml message to 10000 characters in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to implement this logic where in i am creating a new instance of the message if the size exceeds 10000 characters.The type of message will be an XML with header & footer.I need to ensure that i create a new instance every time the message size crosses 10000 characters.I am not able to think where to start.can anyone give lead/pointers that can get me started. By the way,the XML will be generated at run time.

Added Note:

Thanks Thomas for the reply.I'll just try and explain how the xml will be formed.The xml will have it's header & footer which will be fixed.But it'll comprise of one component which will look something like this apart from the normal header & footer :

{4:
:20:XIE180215USD001
:12:101
:77E:20110614BKCHMYKLXXX0000100001CNY00002000000000010000,00
PBBEMYKLXXX8990612000072
00000000200000,00000000030000,00A
MBBEMYKLXXX8990592000072
 
-00000000100000,00000000025000,00RYN
-}

So here in field 77E after the  first line,there will be repetition of line 2 & 3.This needs to happen till the entire size doesn't exceed 10000 characters.I'll then have to stop and then create a new fresh XML.The problem here is how do i count the size of entire XML.Should i count it in the end/Should i count it after every iteration of Field 77E.Also i need to consider the size of the header and footer.After consolidating i  will need to have to check for if the size doesn't exceed 10000 characters.Also i've another blockade.Since these are all strings,i can use the String.length() method to find the length.But how do i convert the same in char.Is that the right thought process.Please help me.I'm just a bit confused here. @Thomas,@Stephen C

Comment: Does that restriction apply to the entire XML or to the contents only? And what's the reason for that restriction? Can you provide an example?

Comment: How are you generating / writing the XML?  What library?  (Hint: this will be difficult with libraries that serialise a DOM or a Java object tree.)

Comment: (I removed some irrelevant tags.  You are NOT parsing the XML ...)

Comment: @Thomas: That restriction applies to the contents only.

Comment: @StephenC : I am using custom formatters to generate the message.

Comment: If the restriction applies to the content only just keep track of the content length and if the new content _would_ violate that restriction create a new xml before writing the message or, if the content is bigger than 10000 characters, split the content in whatever way fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the reply.I'll just try and explain how the xml will be formed.The xml will have it's header & footer which will be fixed.But it'll comprise of one component which will look something like this :


{4:
:20:XIE180215USD001
:12:101
:77E:20110614BKCHMYKLXXX0000100001CNY00002 000000000010000,00
PBBEMYKLXXX8990612000072
00000000200000,00000000030000,00A
MBBEMYKLXXX8990592000072 
-00000000100000,00000000025000,00RYN
-}